# How to Install android studio offline?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I install android studio ,sdk,gradel offline?(I have internet problems)

I tried to install them 3 times online but because of internet problems never installed properly and there were lots of warnings ad errors about sdk and gradel.
Please help